# Hosting postgres wal logs on a separate dedicated server with failover setup

Tags: postgresql, replication, write-ahead-logging, postgresql-11

a **postgres novice** here, so sorry if my questions don't sound meaningful. My postgres server setup goes as follows:

**Master(on server A), Upstream(on B, receiving wal from A), Downstream(on C, receiving wal from B).** *A is streaming wal logs on a few `physical_replication_slots`. All the other servers are created from pg_basebackup of A.*

Now, I've another **server X, dedicated to WAL storage. Whatever be the primary at the moment, its wal logs will be dumped on X inside directory(say /root/wal_logs). There's a `pg_receivewal`(on server X) process receiving this wal from Master and saving it in the same directory.**

Under failover scenarios, slaves are promoted to master, and others act like slaves. So, I wanted to know,

- **How the logs on server X will be affected if masters keep on switching ? Can a new master server create a wal conflicting with the old server's wal ?**
- **What if I create a new standby( D ) from pg_basebackup of A, and try recovering it from these logs ? There was some Timeline kinda concept(which I couldn't grasp much) in postgres wals. Can it have effect on recovery of D ?**
- **And is it possible, for a Master demoted to standby, recover from these logs ? Or will I need pg_rewind for this?**
- **Otherwise, what's the recommended way to do it ?**